# array returning error in java

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code

```
import java.util.*;


    public class nebucha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String amac = "amamamafdfdfdfmasssmamasaaaasssamamsamsamsasssss";
        int[] data = budüzen(amac);

        System.out.println("Votes: " + Arrays.toString(data));

    }

    public static int[] budüzen(String amac) {

        int[] saysaysay = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < amac.length(); i++) {
            if (amac.charAt(i) == 'a') {
                saysaysay[0]++;
            } else if (amac.charAt(i) == 'm') {
                saysaysay[1]++;
            } else if (amac.charAt(i) == 's') {
                saysaysay[2]++;
            }
        }
    }

    return saysaysay[] ;
}
```

i tried to compile it but i dont know why.there was a problem.im seeking a solution

Please help me.

Comment: If you could post the error that is being thrown, we might be able to help.

Comment: For readability purposes, I suggest putting the brackets [] directly after the type without spaces, and then have spaces after that. So instead of int []data, use int[] data. And instead of String[]args, use String[] args.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
return saysaysay[];
```

use

```
return saysaysay;
```

and put it inside the `budüzen` method (it's currently outside).

Here's your class, compilable, will proper indenting. The purpose of indenting is to easily see whether your statements are inside the correct `{}` block:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class nebucha{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        String amac="amamamafdfdfdfmasssmamasaaaasssamamsamsamsasssss";
        int []data=budüzen(amac);

        System.out.println("Votes: "+Arrays.toString(data));
    }

    public static int [] budüzen(String amac){
        int[] saysaysay = new int[3];
        for(int i=0;i<amac.length();i++){
            if(amac.charAt(i)=='a'){
                saysaysay[0]++;
            }else if(amac.charAt(i)=='m'){
                saysaysay[1]++;
            }else if(amac.charAt(i)=='s'){
                saysaysay[2]++;
            }
        }
        return saysaysay;
    }
}
```